# polynomial time in finding constituent prime factors of an integer

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

If given an integer n = pq, p and q are primes, and a way of computing phi(n) in polynomial time is given. Can we also get the value of p and q in polynomial time? The answer is we can, but how?  We can use the method given for finding phi(n) in polynomial time.

Edit:

sorry for causing people to argue, I changed co-prime to prime now. The original problem is solved, but I'm still curious if this conclusion has a general form, I mean if n actually equals to p * r * s * ....It should still be able to get the most basic primes in polynomial time. How to prove?

Comment: $p$ and $q$ are two different primes, or merely supposed coprime integers?

Comment: If $p,q$ are not primes, qe cannot be sure to find them anyway. If we start with $n=30$ and to answer $\{3,10\}$ how could you be sure I didn't have $\{6,5\}$ in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a system of two equations in two unknowns:

$$ n = pq \qquad \qquad \varphi(n) = (p-1)(q-1) $$

Comment: wow.............now I see......

Comment: This only holds if $p, q$ are both primes

Comment: If they are not prime, I'm still able to get the most basic primes in polynomial time using same way, right? e.g. p isn't prime and p = r  s,  so after getting p, I use same way to get r and s ?

Comment: Oh.. I guess it's wrong since I can't use that special phi function if p and q aren't prime. I mean this one phi(p) = p -1

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $p$ and $q$ are the roots of $X^2-(p+q)X+pq$ and for primes $p,q$ we have $\varphi(pq)=(p-1)(q-1)$.

Comment: Since p and q are the roots of a quadratic equation, therefore answer can be solved in polynomial time?

Answer (score 2):

If $p, q$ are coprime, $\varphi(pq) = \varphi(p)\varphi(q)$. The problem of finding the totient function is equivalent to factoring, and no one has found a polynomial time algorithm for that.

If $p,q$ are primes, $\varphi(pq) = (p-1)(q-1)$.

Comment: Is it because we can just search from p = 1 to p = n to get the answer, therefore it's in polynomial time?

Comment: @Arch: $O(n)$ is exponential time in the size of the input, because the size of the input is $O(\log n)$.

Comment: @Arch1tect I have revised my answer, it is not in polynomial time unless $p,q$ are primes

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ Knowing $\,\color{#c00}{c = pq},\,$ and $\, \color{blue}{\phi(pq)}= (p-1)(q-1)\,$ we know $\,\color{#0a0}b = p+q = \color{#c00}{pq}-1-\color{blue}{\phi(pq)}.\,$ 
Thus we know  $\,\color{#0a0}{b = p+q}\,$ and $\,\color{#c00}{c = pq},\,$ so we can solve for $\,p,q\,$ as the roots of  a *known* quadratic

$$(x-p)(x-q)\,=\, x^2 -(\color{#0a0}{p+q}) x +\color{#c00}{pq}\, =\ \overbrace{x^2 - \color{#0a0}b\,x + \color{#c00}c}^{\large \color{#0a0}b,\ \color{#c00}c\,\ { known}}$$

Comment: I believe this only holds if $p,q$ are both primes

Comment: @qwr Presumably that is what the OP means by "co-*primes*", i.e. coprime primes, i.e. distinct primes.

Comment: coprimes mean that they are relatively prime, I don't think you can make the conclusion they are both prime

Comment: @qwr The issue is what *the OP* means by "co-primes", not what "coprime" means generally. Most likely it means what I wrote, given the context. Update: it does, see the OP's edit.

Comment: Sorry for causing the argument. I have edited it..